# setting dynamic text value in Actionscript

Tags: flash, actionscript, dynamic-text

I have a symbol called MapNameText and a dynamic text field inside called "innerText".

I'm trying to make it change the text when i click on the object they're all in but it doesnt work

### Relevant part of my actionscript:

```
var MapName:String;

this.onMouseDown = function()
{

    trace(MapNameText['innerText'].text);

    MapName= MapNameText['innerText'].text;

    switch(MapName)
    {
        case "Classic":
        this.MapNameText['innerText'].text = "Crystal";
        trace(this.MapNameText['innerText'].text);

        case "Crystal":
        MapNameText['innerText'].text = "Volcano";

        case "Volcano":
        MapNameText['innerText'].text = "Classic";
    }
}
```

---

In the output window i get
"Classic"
"Crystal"
But the text doesn't update in my object, it's confusing me a lot and im not sure what to do

Can anyone please lend me a hand with how to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the reply! unfortunately that didn't resolve the issue, but after a little more tinkering a realized that i wasn't using 'Break'. It now works when i break off each case.

for those with a similar problem, this is the resolved code

```
switch(MapName)
{
    case "Classic":
    this.MapNameText.innerText.text = "Crystal";
    trace(this.MapNameText['innerText'].text);
    break;

    case "Crystal":
    MapNameText.innerText.text = "Volcano";
    break;

    case "Volcano":
    MapNameText.innerText.text = "Classic";
    break;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
switch(MapName)
{
    case "Classic":
    this.MapNameText.innerText.text = "Crystal";
    trace(this.MapNameText['innerText'].text);

    case "Crystal":
    MapNameText.innerText.text = "Volcano";

    case "Volcano":
    MapNameText.innerText.text = "Classic";
}
```